# DataFrame add a dataframe row that is sum each row's sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python and i have a question. I have an exported .csv with values and i want to sum each row's total value than make a total column to there.

I've tried that but it doesnt work.

```
import pandas as pd


wine = pd.read_csv('testelek.csv', 'rb', delimiter=';')

wine['Total'] = [wine[row].sum(axis=1) for row in wine]
```

I want to make my DataFrame like this.

```
              101       102       103       104   ....   Total     
__________________________________________________________________________
    0         80        84        86        78   ....     328
    1         78        76        77        79   ....     310
    2         79        81        88        83   ....     331
    3         70        85        89        84   ....     328            
    4         78        84        88        85   ....     335
```

Comment: Do you mean add a column (as opposed to row)?

Comment: Please provide an excerpt of `wine` and the result you expect.

Comment: Moreover, your list comprehension is not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the need for the list comprehension and just use the `axis=1` parameter to get what you want.

```
wine['Total'] = wine.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: That helped! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do this is by using `.apply()`. 
Suppose that you want to create a new column named `Total` by adding the values per row for columns named `101`, `102`, and `103` you can try the following:

```
wine['Total'] = wine.apply(lambda row: sum([row['101'], row['102'], row['103']]), axis=1)
```